# Mongodb aggregation - min but not zero

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection with array field:

```
{[
  name:String
  buyPrice:Int
  sellPrice:Int
]}
```

I am trying to find min and max buy/sell price. At some entries buy or sell price is zero so I need to find min price but greater than zero.
Here is my query:

```
{
  name: '$_id',
  maxBuyPrice: {
    $max: '$commodities.buyPrice'
  },
  minBuyPrice: {
    $min: '$commodities.buyPrice'
  },
  maxSellPrice: {
    $max: '$commodities.sellPrice'
  },
  minSellPrice: {
    $min: '$commodities.sellPrice'
  }
}
```

I can't use `$match` operator with `$gt` because I can lost entries with max values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- `$filter` to iterate loop of `commodities.buyPrice` array and get filtered price that is greater than 0
- apply `$min` in above filtered result
- `$ifNull` to check if above `$min` result is null then return only 0

```
  {
    $project: {
      name: "$_id",
      maxBuyPrice: { $max: "$commodities.buyPrice" },
      minBuyPrice: {
        $ifNull: [
          {
            $min: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$commodities.buyPrice",
                cond: { $gt: ["$$this", 0] }
              }
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      },
      maxSellPrice: { $max: "$commodities.sellPrice" },
      minSellPrice: {
        $ifNull: [
          {
            $min: {
              $filter: {
                input: "$commodities.sellPrice",
                cond: { $gt: ["$$this", 0] }
              }
            }
          },
          0
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/OdFLOpARses)

Comment: note that this will give null value if all entry values are 0

Comment: @TomSlabbaert thanks i have updated answer with solution.

Comment: Many thanks. Upvoted, but I have <15 rep so it doesn't show